# Is the gamepad support in The Witcher 2: Enhanced Edition the same as in the Xbox 360 version?

Tags: pc, the-witcher-2, controllers

The Witcher 2 already had gamepad support, I know that, but with the Xbox 360 "Enhanced Edition" this has been completely rehauled to better fit the Xbox 360 controller and console play, alongside the UI and all menus in the game.

What I want to know is: Does the current version of The Witcher 2, which I believe is also called "Enhanced Edition" (if not, I probably wouldn't even be asking this question) use the overhauled Xbox 360 control scheme when you're playing with a gamepad or does it use the older version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While *Witcher 2* has always had (really good) [support for the 360 controller](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/975399-/59357008), **the Enhanced Edition's revised 360 controls currently *have not* made it to the PC Enhanced Edition**. [Kotaku](http://kotaku.com/5901592/the-witcher-2-makes-it-to-xbox-360-intact-and-ready-for-sexy-action):

> Weirdly, the 360's enhanced controller setup doesn't make its way over to the PC version of the Enhanced Edition, which bummed me out. I'm one of the odd ones who played The Witcher 2 with a controller on PC, and I find that I prefer the 360's button layout and targeting system, which feel a touch different (and are arranged differently) on the PC.